# Passing an SDL_Surface or clip_rect

Tags: c++, sdl

I'm trying to write a bit of code in which I check to see if the mouse has been clicked on a certain SDL Surface. In the code example below, I have the SDL_Surface background which I am trying to check against the mouse position.

```
bool checkCollide(int myx, int myy, SDL_Surface* objectOne){
    if(myx < objectOne->clip_rect.x) return false;
    if(myx > objectOne->clip_rect.x + objectOne->clip_rect.w) return false;
    if(myy < objectOne->clip_rect.y) return false;
    if(myy > (objectOne->clip_rect.y + objectOne->clip_rect.h)) return false;
    return true;
}

void main(){
SDL_Surface* background;
while(SDL_PollEvent(&event)){
    if(event.type == SDL_MOUSEBUTTONDOWN){
        if(checkCollide(event.button.x, event.button.y, background){
            // run events
        }
    }
}
```

The problem I'm having is that when I try to run it as shown above, the code compiles fine but doesn't do anything. The collision check always fails. I have tried it in a lot of various combinations, including changing the parameters of checkCollide to SDL_Rect and passing the Surface's clip_rect property. The only completely successful way I've done it is to have a separate SDL_Rect with the same size and location as the SDL_Surface, and to check the collision against that. When I run it that way, it all works as I expect it to. Why isn't the surface (or clip_rect) passing correctly, or if it is, what am I doing wrong in the checkCollide function to cause it to fail?

Comment: Are you sure the background has a correct clip_rect with a proper width height?  Also make sure the x and y coords of the background are correct too.

Comment: I'm not too experienced with SDL in particular, but it would appear that because 'background' is a pointer to garbage, and that passing '&background' would be an SDL_Surface**, rather than the SDL_Surface* that the function looks for, that this should not have compiled, and should be giving segmentation faults.

Comment: greedybuddha: I tried setting the clip_rect properties at the beginning of the program manually, to no avail.

metredigm: I guess it's possible, I'm not really familiar with ** pointers. I made an error in transcribing my code above, in the call to checkCollide, the SDL_Surface argument is just "background", not "&background". I've edited it to reflect this. I did a bit of research and tried every combination I can think of, but the only one that even compiles is the one I've got.

Answer (score 0):

The clip_rect property is not what you think it is:

From the SDL docs:

> The clip_rect field is the clipping rectangle as set by
>   SDL_SetClipRect.

and SDL_SetClipRect

> Sets the clipping rectangle for a surface. When this surface is the
>   destination of a blit, only the area within the clip rectangle will be
>   drawn into.
>
> The rectangle pointed to by rect will be clipped to the edges of the
>   surface so that the clip rectangle for a surface can never fall
>   outside the edges of the surface.
>
> If rect is NULL the clipping rectangle will be set to the full size of
>   the surface.

The problem is, that when you test the collision later on, the clip_rect x,y are always set to 0. The surface itself does not know about it's position on the screen.

A solution to this would be to create a Sprite like class that will have a Rect and a Surface.

Comment: Looks like you're right. I was hoping to avoid using a separate Rect corresponding to each Surface, but I guess I don't have much of a choice. Thanks for your help!